# Check if value of one dictionary is the key for the other

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I basically want to check if the value in one dictionary is the key in the other.

So for example, I have two dictionaries

```
a = {armani: jeans, dolce: gabbana}
b = {jeans: robo, jobs: versace}
```

I wrote code to do the check such that it only obtains the values that is the key in the other dictionary. So in this case, I just want to display `{armani: robo}` as jeans was already in both. So like the value of jeans in the second dictionary then becomes the main value in the new final dictionary

This is the code:

```
{k:v for k,v in a.items() if v in b.items()}
```

But it doesn't work and I don't know how to do the check to see if the value is the key in another list

Comment: @MegaBluejay so like what do I need to change

Comment: Mind if I ask what `jeans: robo` represents?  Never heard of robo if it is a brand.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
{k:b[v] for k,v in a.items() if v in b}
```

You were just missing two elements:

1. You don't need to write `if v in b.items()` because Python interprets `if v in b` as "if v is in the keys of b".
2. You need to map k not to v itself, but to v's value in b, which is `b[v]`.

Comment: But then it isn't printing the `armani: robo`. So like it should extract the value for jeans and then replace it for armani jeans

Comment: Do you mean it should replace the value in a, or that it should produce a new dictionary?

Comment: As in I am creating a new dictionary that takes the key of the first dictionary, so `Armani` and then value of the `Jeans` (which is the key of the second dictionary). In that case, `Jeans` value is `robo`.

Comment: You may also want to put quotes around the values in your dictionary, like this: `a = {'armani': 'jeans', 'dolce': 'gabbana'}`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could filter with set intersection.

```
a = {'armani': 'jeans', 'dolce': 'gabbana'}
b = {'jeans': 'robo', 'jobs': 'versace'}
c = set(a.values()).intersection(b)
d = {k:b[k] for k in c}

# or as a one-liner
e = {k:b[k] for k in set(a.values()).intersection(b)}
```

It might be faster than looping through the whole dictionary.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: I just tested the code above in Python 2.7 and Python 3.7 and it works fine. You may have to do something like this in an older version: c = set(a.values()).intersection(set(b.keys()))

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
a = {"armani": "jeans", "dolce": "gabbana"}
b = {"jeans": "robo", "jobs": "versace"}

res = {k1:v2 for k1,v1 in a.items() for k2,v2 in b.items() if v1 ==k2}

print(res)
```

Output:

```
{'armani': 'robo'}
```